# index of a selected child in a form

Tags: javascript, focus, onchange

I have created a "dynamically" form with some child with the same Name.
If I have to change something I can do a for cycle with:
`myForm.NAME[i].value`
for example.
But the problem is that I wanna activate a javascript function "changeGroup()" and I call it
with:
`onchange="changeGroup(this)"`
In the js function I wanna understand the index of the tag focused without using JQuery.
How can I do?
The tag used is < select >

Answer (score 1):

Like this...

```
function changeGroup(oThis)
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < oThis.form.NAME.length ; i++)
    {
        if (oThis.form.NAME[i] === oThis) {
            alert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to deal with situation when there is only one element with name NAME as in that case oThis.form.NAME won't be array.